# How do I get rosmake to call cmake

Tags: rosmake, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a minimal example. ROS Package A depends on ROS Package B. The authors of these packages did not distribute Makefiles, because they contain hard-coded paths to their computers. Therefore, I need to call `cmake .` and then `make`.

I would like to to call `rosmake A` and have it call cmake on both A and B and then make. Is that possible?

Currently, it just skips over any package without a Makefile:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> A [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< A  No Makefile in package A
```

I do not want to copy their code into a new package, because I would need to do that every time that the authors publish a new version.

In addition, when I create my ROS Package C, which depends on A, I don't want the users of my package to have problems compiling, because they are not necessarily familiar with ROS. I want them to type `rosmake C` and have everything working as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9509/how-do-i-get-rosmake-to-call-cmake/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2011-03-27**:
I updated the question to make it clearer, because I still don't have an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When wrapping 3rd party packages you need to write a custom Makefile for that package which will download and build the 3rd party package.  An example of calling cmake is the [kdl](https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/183f0cc66429/kdl/Makefile) package.  A slightly simpler example is [bfl](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/common/trunk/bfl/Makefile).

If you want other packages to build first you must add dependencies on that package.  And export required compile and link flags.  I highly recommend you go through the [Beginner Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) which covers how to create and use ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0